# Unable to read my newly created Kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes

I set my secret like this:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic aws-region VAL=eu-west-1 \
>           -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
secret "aws-region" replaced
```

Seems to be set:

```
kubectl get secret | ack region
aws-region                      Opaque                                0         20m
```

An I try to read it like this:

```
 76             - name: AWS_REGION
 77               valueFrom:
 78                 secretKeyRef:
 79                   name: aws-region
 80                   key: VAL
```

But that gives a **CreateContainerConfigError** when I run `kubectl apply -f service.yml` 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only showing us a small part of `service.yaml` it's impossible to tell where the error comes from but I can confirm the following works (using a test pod I created [here](https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/18e4be34eac8bcec3d314f82edcf7199)):

```
$ kubectl create secret generic aws-region --from-literal=VAL=eu-west-1
$ kubectl apply -f pod.yaml 
$ kubectl describe po/envfromsecret
Name:         envfromsecret
Namespace:    default
...
Environment:
 AWS_REGION:  <set to the key 'VAL' in secret 'aws-region'>  Optional: false
```

*UPDATE*: I now noticed that the `DATA` column in the output of your `kubectl get secret` command is actually 0, that is, it's empty. Consider using the form I used above (with `--from-literal=`) to create the secret.